# How to set PATH to use Java and Python simultaneously

Tags: java, python, windows, path

I was just wondering if there was any way to set to `%PATH%` variables so I can compile my Java code, along with my Python code?

For instance.. PATH is currently `C:\ ... JDK_bin blah blah`, and that's it. To run my python code, I have to change my path variable completely.

Any answers?

Answer (score 9):

Just add a semicolon after your present path, and write the new one after that.

```
set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\blah\blah";C:\Python31\;C:\Windows\System32
```

etc...

Answer (score 7):

You need to **add** the path to python exe to your existing `PATH` variable which already has path to Java exes and many more paths in it.

```
path = %PATH%;C:\path\to\python\bin
```

You can also do this using windows [**GUI**](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Note that doing an absolute assignment to `PATH` like

```
set PATH = C:\path\to\python\bin
```

will **overwrite** it, loosing the path(s) it already had.

Answer (score 4):

PATH variables can have multiple paths in them. Separate paths with ; on Windows and : on *nix.

```
set PATH=c:\path\to\java;c:\path\to\python
```